# Find break times in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am needing to find break times for users.  I have a table that has login times, logout times, reason code, etc.  Basically the first time entry after an ENDSHIFT entry is the login time for a new day.

Example Table: Times

```
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME          USER_ID  LOGIN_TIME              LOGOUT_TIME             REASON_CODE
1.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-10 00:24:10.357 2015-08-10 02:34:47.973 ENDSHIFT
2.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-11 17:13:38.957 2015-08-11 19:15:45.437 BREAK   
3.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-11 19:41:25.613 2015-08-11 21:38:26.380 BREAK   
4.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-11 22:20:23.600 2015-08-11 23:59:58.337 BREAK   
5.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-12 00:23:58.767 2015-08-12 01:53:45.067 ENDSHIFT
6.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-12 17:14:06.747 2015-08-12 18:57:05.660 BREAK   
7.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-12 19:26:11.790 2015-08-12 21:32:21.683 BREAK   
8.John          Doe             10091   2015-08-12 22:13:35.030 2015-08-12 23:22:31.413 ENDSHIFT
```

I am looking for a result simalar to this:

```
Date         Break Time(hh:mm:ss)
8-11-2015    1:17:37
```

Comment: Is it your source data or the desired result?

Comment: That is the source data

Comment: What do you mean "find break times"? Do you need to know how long was the break or simply select all rows with REASON CODE = BREAK?

Comment: OK. Now post your desired result and explain how it should be obtained.

Comment: Find the amount of time not clocked in.  If you look at the difference between the first two 'BREAK lines you will see that logout time was 19:15:45 the login time for the next line is 19:41:25.  I am looking for those break times.  It should be 25 minutes and 40 seconds of break time.  Then I need to add all of the break times together per shift.  I don't want to find the amount of time between shifts though.  Just the break times

Comment: Do you mean something like `SUM(logout_in_minutes - login_in_minutes) WHERE reason_code = "BREAK"` ?

Comment: Not really.  I am looking for the difference between the logout time of line 2 and the login time of line 3.  Then I am needing to sum those totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this.  Not sure if it is the most efficient but this is what I have.

```
SELECT NAME, OPERATOR, STARTDATE, USERLOG_ID, (SHIFT-BREAKS1)BREAKS, ACTUAL_TIME
FROM(

SELECT a.NAME, a.OPERATOR, a.STARTDATE, a.USERLOG_ID, SUM(b.Breaks)BREAKS1, SUM(c.SHIFT)SHIFT, SUM(a.ACTUAL_TIME)ACTUAL_TIME
FROM(
 select 
    w.NAME,
    rtrim(u.FIRST_NAME)+ ' '+ rtrim(u.LAST_NAME) OPERATOR,
    rtrim(convert(varchar(12),min(ul.LOGIN_TIME),101)) STARTDATE,
    ul.USERLOG_ID,
    oi.INOUTLOG_ID,
    rtrim(substring(cast(min(oi.LOGOUT_TIME) as varchar(20)),12,8)) LOGOUT_TIME,
DATEDIFF(Minute, oi.LOGIN_TIME, oi.LOGOUT_TIME)Breaks,
max(e.DESCRIPTION) EXITREASON,
sum(isnull(a.ACTUAL_TIME/60/60,0))  ACTUAL_TIME
from
userlog ul
left outer join assignment a
    on ul.USERLOG_ID = a.USERLOG_ID
left outer join users u 
    on ul.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
left outer join inoutlog oi
    on ul.USERLOG_ID = oi.USERLOG_ID
left outer join jobtype j
    on j.JOBTYPE_ID = u.JOBTYPE_ID 
left outer join warehouse w
    on w.WAREHOUSE_ID = a.WAREHOUSE_ID
left outer join exitreason e
    on oi.EXITREASON_ID = e.EXITREASON_ID    
where 
ul.LOGIN_TIME between @BeginTime and @EndTime

group by
w.NAME,
ul.USERLOG_ID,
u.FIRST_NAME,
u.LAST_NAME,
oi.INOUTLOG_ID,
ul.LOGIN_TIME,
e.LABOR_ID,
e.LOGOUT,
ul.LOGOUT_TIME,
oi.LOGIN_TIME,
oi.LOGOUT_TIME
  )a
LEFT JOIN(
select 
ul.USERLOG_ID,
DATEDIFF(Minute, oi.LOGIN_TIME, oi.LOGOUT_TIME)Breaks,
oi.INOUTLOG_ID
from
userlog ul
left outer join inoutlog oi
    on ul.USERLOG_ID = oi.USERLOG_ID
left outer join exitreason e
    on oi.EXITREASON_ID = e.EXITREASON_ID
where 
ul.LOGIN_TIME between @BeginTime and @EndTime AND e.DESCRIPTION = 'BREAK'

)b ON a.USERLOG_ID = b.USERLOG_ID AND a.INOUTLOG_ID = b.INOUTLOG_ID
LEFT JOIN(
select 
ul.USERLOG_ID,
DATEDIFF(Minute, ul.LOGIN_TIME, ul.LOGOUT_TIME)SHIFT,
oi.INOUTLOG_ID
from
userlog ul
left outer join inoutlog oi
    on ul.USERLOG_ID = oi.USERLOG_ID
left outer join exitreason e
    on oi.EXITREASON_ID = e.EXITREASON_ID
where 
ul.LOGIN_TIME between @BeginTime and @EndTime AND e.DESCRIPTION = 'END OF SHIFT'
)c ON a.USERLOG_ID = c.USERLOG_ID AND a.INOUTLOG_ID = c.INOUTLOG_ID
GROUP BY a.NAME, a.OPERATOR, a.STARTDATE, a.USERLOG_ID
    )z
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for? Have not actually tested the code.

```
Select
    First_Name
    ,Last_Name
    ,User_ID
    ,convert(varchar(10), dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, Login_Time),0), 111) as "Date"
    ,convert(varchar(5), sum(Datediff(mi, Login_Time, Logout_Time)), 114) as "Break Time"
From
    Times
Where
    Reason = 'Break'
Group by
    First_Name
    ,Last_Name
    ,User_ID
    ,dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, Login_Time),0)
```

Comment: Kind of.  That gets me the difference in the times on the same line.  I am need the difference between the Login_Time on line B(circled in red) and the Logout-Time on line A(circled in yellow).  Here is a screen clip of what I am talking about.

http://imgur.com/R739z2B